# Find elements $f,g\in\mathrm{End}(V)$ such that $f\circ g=id_V$ and $f,g\not\in \mathrm{End}(V)^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, ring-theory

Let $K$ be a field. Given $V$ a $K$ vector-space containing all sequences $a=(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ with values from $K$, such that $a_n\neq 0$ for only finitely many $n\in \mathbb N$.

I want to to find $f,g\in\mathrm{End}(V)$ such that $f\circ g=id_V$ and $f,g\not\in\mathrm{End}(V)^{\times}.$

Answer (score 4):

You may use "conveyor belt" maps, for instance $f(a_{0},a_{1},\dotsc)=(a_{1},a_{2},\dotsc)$ and $g(a_{0},a_{1},\dotsc)=(0,a_{0},a_{1},a_{2},\dotsc)$.

Analogously, in a polynom or regular functions space, you may use derivation and primitivation relatively to a given point. That's essentially what I've done.

Comment: The "conveyor belt" is usually called _left shift operator_ for obvious reason. (It is always nice to know names to remember and to search.) This is an example that retraction and section are not necessary isomorphism.